# My application wont run in command line?

Tags: c#, wpf, batch-file, exe

I made a WPF application, and i would like to run it in .bat file so i can put it in Windows Media Center! But my .bat file doesnt work, it doesnt open the .exe file, when i try to manually type it in CMD, it opens directly. What could i be doing wrong?
This is my code line.

```
   "C:\Users\Fer\Documents\Test Batch\Debug\smartHomeTest.exe"
```

This is the only line in the .bat file, I even tried a .cmd, but that doesn't do it?
Is there any code that i should write in my WPF application so it will run a bat file?

Comment: If you run the *batch file* from a command prompt (rather than running your exe), do you get an error message?

Comment: yes, the only error i get is the application has stopped working.
But in cmd it runs perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the job

```
   cd C:\Users\Fer\Documents\Test Batch\Debug\
   cd
   smartHomeTest.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**: Try Start "" /wait "C:\Users\Fer\Documents\Test Batch\Debug\smartHomeTest.exe"

Comment: try this start "" /wait  "C:\Users\Fer\Documents\Test Batch\Debug\smartHomeTest.exe"

Comment: i dont understand what u are doing, with empty quotes, but i copied it and it doenst work :(

Comment: can you try to run something like "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" through bat file, just to test your group policy or some antivirus setting is not blocking this. Also do you see anything in event log related to this?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a shortcut to your application, setting the working directory to your Debug dir, then call the shortcut from your batch, does that help?

Comment: I mean the directory the application is started from. I don´t have an english windows ready, but it should be something like "Run in", right above the selection for the hotkey